# my EventListener are not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

What I'm trying to do is, if I hover over one of my drawn objects, I want to display a blurb saying which city it is, the population and an image of their downtown etc. as of right now i just trying yo get it to work. i also wondering if there something else i can you instead of alert, something that would make a bubble instead

```
<script>
    function startCanvas() {
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      //first circle
      var one = c.getContext("2d");
      //second circle
      var two = c.getContext("2d");
      //third cirle
      var three = c.getContext("2d");
      //fourth circle
      var four = c.getContext("2d");
      //fifth cirle
      var five = c.getContext("2d");
      // new image
      var image = new Image();
      image.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 69, 50);
        //draw a circle
        one.beginPath();
        one.arc(180, 90, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        one.closePath();
        one.fill();
        two.beginPath();
        two.arc(155, 138, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        two.closePath();
        two.fill();
        three.beginPath();
        three.arc(160, 180, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        three.closePath();
        three.fill();
        four.beginPath();
        four.arc(257, 210, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        four.closePath();
        four.fill();
        five.beginPath();
        five.arc(238, 235, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        five.closePath();
        five.fill();
      };
      image.src = 'denmark.jpg';



    //function hover over circle one, give alert
      one.addEventListener('mouseover',  
       function (e) {
           e = e || window.event;
           alert('this is a test');
       }
       );


    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="startCanvas()">
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600";">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
      </canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will throw this error

- **Object # < CanvasRenderingContext2D > has no method 'addEventListener'**

So Modify this part

```
  //function hover over circle one, give alert
  one.addEventListener('mouseover',  
   function (e) {
       e = e || window.event;
       alert('this is a test');
   }
   );
```

by this code

```
//function hover over circle one, give alert
  c.addEventListener('mouseover',  
   function (e) {
       e = e || window.event;
       alert('this is a test');
   }
   ,false);
```

This Will Work;

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a slightly higher-level drawing library, such as [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html)? Or [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS)?

I've messed around with both of these, and they make this kind of interactive canvas work much more elegant, and will also improve your cross-browser compatibility.